# iFrame functionality with Ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I need to include a small form from a reservation PHP module that I downloaded to my website. Its documentation says that it has to be included with iFrame. However the place is restricted, so the iFrame overflows when the date picker is opened and scrolling bars are shown.

To solve this, I tried using jQuery so that the div would be overflowed.

```
<div id="siteloader">
            <script>
                    $(function(){
                    $('#siteloader').load('<?php echo base_url('booking/form_homepage.php')?>');
                    });
                </script>
</div>
```

However, it results that it loads only the HTML. This is not necessary for me, since the page I want to load comes from a complete module, so I need it to be loaded complete, basically what the iFrame would do.

Is there any way to achieve this with Ajax/jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty good with jQuery/AJAX but I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about. What do you mean "the iFrame overflows", and why do you think jQuery would help with that problem? Why does the PHP module require using an iFrame? Can you link us to that module so we can examine it and see if jQuery/AJAX would help in your case?

Comment: The datepicker is too big for the iframe so scrollbars are rendered on the iframe while the datepicker is open.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Can you expand the size of the iFrame as part of opening the datepicker, and then re-size it again on datepicker close?  Also, what is the PHP module you are using? Why do you think AJAX would help?

Comment: @gibberish http://codecanyon.net/item/online-hotel-booking-system/2680320 This is the PHP module I am using, but my website is created with CodeIgniter, so it follows a different structure, which somehow does not allow me (I am not sure however) to integrate the module by creating different forms and connecting it with the application logic of the downloaded module

Comment: I am tempted to step away from this question because I don't know the answer, but since no one else is stepping up I can at least help you to brainstorm.  Would setting the overflow property to hidden via jQuery's .css() method do the trick? Or would that cause the datepicker itself to be clipped?